# How to open mutilple instances of the Terminal?

Tags: multiple-instances

In former releases of Ubuntu, one could easily have an independent Terminal Window open in each workspace. For example, One could be used for editing program code, another compiling and linking and a third one for testing, each in it's own workspace.

But In Ubuntu 12.04,  it seems that each workspace can only contain another but different application ?

Answer (score 7):

You can always open a new window of an application by middle-clicking on the application icon in the launcher. The windows can be placed wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

With Unity drag the terminal icon to the Launcher bar. When you want an additional Terminal right click on it and select New Terminal.

You can right click on the top decoration on each Terminal window you want to move and choose 'Move to Another Workspace'.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-terminal`.

OR

Enter `gnome-terminal` in a *terminal*, and open a *new tab* in *that* terminal that you entered `gnome-terminal` into, so you have two free terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Workspace icon. then go to a specific workspace.

Press `Super+A` key to bring the dash. Type `terminal` and hit on the terminal icon. You have now a terminal window on that workspace.

Now again click on the workspace icon, switch to another workspace. Repeat the process for Creating another terminal window. (You can also right-click on the terminal icon on launcher and select **New Terminal** option to have another window, or Just Middle click on the icon).

This way you can have multiple terminal windows on multiple workspaces.

See the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> twice then press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and drag one terminal to the workspace you want.

**Method 2:**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Personally, I like the second choice.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to user **Terminator** application(it can be installed from Software Center) which is very nice and do exactly what you want. I use it myself too.