# How to restore "Open new terminal" by right click in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, 17.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. I also noticed that my familiar routine of right-clicking the terminal icon in the launcher and selecting "open new terminal" no longer exists. Is there a way I can restore that "open new terminal" right-click option to the launcher?

I learned from [How to open mutilple instances of the Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152192/how-to-open-mutilple-instances-of-the-terminal) that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal even faster, or I can Window+A then type terminal. These are great shortcuts, but separate from this question.

Comment: Have you checked the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu)? They may or may not be outdated.

Comment: @b_laoshi - Thx, but those are specific to using the right-click within nautilus to get a terminal at a particular $PWD, as opposed to right-clicking from launcher. I just tested nautilus and I can open with a right-click there. Probably added as a default by now.

Comment: My bad. I really should have read more closely. You may be aware, but Ubuntu 18.04 is ditching Unity for Gnome. If you're going to stick with the default interface, maybe an early switch to Ubuntu Gnome is worth considering as well, maybe not. I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if the right-click option you describe still exists in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. Sorry I wasn't much help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did also a fresh install of 17.04 coming from 16.04 and found the same issue.

I managed to get it working with:

```
sudo pico(or whatever editor) /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
```

and commented out this line:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity7;
```

with end result:

```
#OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity7;
```

For now is working for me. Hope this helps you as well.

Comment: Worked beautifully for me. I didn't even have to reboot or restart unity or anything. Thanks!

Comment: I raised the same question here at https://askubuntu.com/questions/904680/unity-17-04-desktop-launcher-problem-for-terminal?rq=1.  I reported this bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1681523.  Be aware that you may need change also/instead the file at `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`